# @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate and Double/Float boxing

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot, boxing

So, I am writing some code which would result in boxing primitive types in the innermost loops. I had a look at `Integer.valueOf` to check what `int` range is cached - by the way: why only `Byte` range by default? - and noticed first, that - to my satisfaction - the range is configurable by a JVM property, and then, that is an intrinsic method. This seemed a bit strange because the method is pretty minimal and I would expect Hotspot-compiled and inlined code to already be optimal, but ok. Then I moved to floating point values, and they are still intrinsic, despite the methods literaly just calling the classe's constructor, as there is no obvious caching strategy.

What optimizations can Hotspot do (as in, some jvm implementations do) when boxing floting point primitives?

Comment: You’re question is based on the assumption that the JVM’s intrinsic handling of those methods has to do exactly the same as their Java code, but the whole point of the intrinsic handling is that it can do *different* things.

Comment: First, the question does ask what it can do differently. Second, I am not sure to what extent it's true. Documentation says that semantics of the java method and intrinsic code must match. It can be argued that, as referential (in)equality is observable, it is a part of semantics of the method.

Comment: You said, “this seemed a bit strange because the method is pretty minimal”, so you *are* assuming that the Java code, which is the one that is “pretty minimal” has a relevance for the intrinsic handling. Even worse with the floating point classes: “as there is no obvious caching strategy”. There is no caching strategy *in the Java code*, but since [the semantics of the `valueOf` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(double)) allows caching, there is no reason why the intrinsic handling can not inject a caching strategy.

Comment: Failed to note this comment. What I meant by 'no obvious caching strategy' was meant as in general, no algorithm comes to mind. I thought it was clear from the question, especially that it would be very hard to become confused with the Java implementation...

Comment: I’m not sure what you are trying to say. When it would be “hard to become confused”, that would be a good thing. Whatever problem you are trying to construct here, it does not exists. The JVM can easily replace any method by an intrinsic method and it does so for a lot methods. Besides that, [you got an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65386230/2711488) and keep ignoring it.

Answer (score 3):

`Double.valueOf`, `Float.valueOf`, as well as other similar `valueOf`s, are intrinsic methods in HotSpot JVM. The JVM indeed [knows](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/1e249ca8d585/src/hotspot/share/ci/ciMethod.cpp#l1316) about these methods and treats them specially.

There is [EliminateAutoBox](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/1e249ca8d585/src/hotspot/share/opto/c2_globals.hpp#l501) optimization, which is turned on by default. The idea of the optimization is to get rid of redundant boxing/unboxing. JIT compiler looks for matching `Double.valueOf()`/`doubleValue()` pairs and, if possible, eliminates both calls together.